# Drag and Drop Knowing children.length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to allow users to order categories by dragging and dropping. 
I have a code working but it just drags and drop a div into another, I need to make sure if there's a div there already he switches instead of dropping but I'm having a lot of problems.

I tried to count the children of the div before dropping but it always returns 0.

Here's my code:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
var kids = $(data > "div").length;
alert(kids);
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

I have a cycle generating a number of this divs (div's id is managed)

```
 <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<div id="<%=categoria_prato.id%>"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style =  "width:100px; height:25px">Ola</div>
```

Comment: `$(data > "div").length;` isn't a valid selector.  Perhapse you meant `$('#' + data + ' > div').length;`?  Also, it would be helpful if you provided some HTML so we can figure out the selector based on the structure.

Comment: I'm following tutorials. I want to know if there's already a div inside the main div. Because if it does that means it's already "chosen" and can't have another div inside

Comment: Ok, try updating the selector to what I provided above and we'll go from there.  It should translate to $('#mainDiv > div') which will look for divs as immediate children of the main div by id which is passed by your setData.

Comment: still not working :x just says 0 all the time... even if i put all 6 divs there

Comment: So your categoria_prato.id div has 6 divs inside it?

Comment: it's a cycle. im creating 6 divs with id's (1,2,3,4,5,6) which are draggable and i have 6 divs with id "div1" which gets the draggable divs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112802/discussion-between-zach-and-boltz0r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code was that you were checking to see if the dragging div had child divs rather than the drop div.  The check should be in the allowDrop which will set ev.preventDefault() if it will accept drops.  There are much better examples out there for drag and drops but here is an example based on your scenario:

HTML

```
<div id="drop1" class="dropDiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="drop2" class="dropDiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="draggable1" draggable="true" class="dragDiv" ondragstart="drag(event)">
Drag me #1
</div>
<div id="draggable2" draggable="true" class="dragDiv" ondragstart="drag(event)">
Drag me #2
</div>
```

JS

```
function drop(ev) {
  var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  $('#' + id).appendTo(ev.target);
}
function allowDrop(ev) {
    // Only check the parent div with id starting with drop and not the child div
  if(ev.target.id.indexOf('drop') == 0) {
    var count = $('#' + ev.target.id + ' > div').length;
    if(count < 1) {
      //allow the drop
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
      // NOPE
    }
  }
}
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/astynax777/dq3emchj/23/

Comment: My fiddle was attempting to show a dragover and dragleave event but the dragleave event wasn't firing so I just forego-ed it.